# Missing transaction in phantom wallet shows up on Solscan

Tags: wallet, phantom, error, missing

I recently sent 1 sol from my trading bot to my phantom wallet. the solscan says the sol is there but the wallet is not reporting the funds? Thanks

Wallet

4MiXCxn6ybEuk1G5SMTihCpZERd2RFZYTrFuGcWQhB4V

Transaction

https://solscan.io/tx/3KoxGbvww2GHJK7ceEFY8KGmskMy5WnwYuvEn4Mf3x8Wq6gQphKMRfU5HiV2yKnVwPAAGY1iMVboiU83LJNLUavM

Comment: Sounds like a case for phantom wallet support.